# get weights for each layer of the model using OpenVINO API

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, openvino

I'd like to get the tensor of weights and biases for each layer of the network using the C++/Python API on the OpenVINO framework. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59930994/get-parameters-weights-for-each-layer-of-the-model-using-the-c-api-on-openvino?newreg=af6f60fc4b124af3ba3ed76aa8b05eaa) but unfortunately it uses an older API (release 2019 R3.1) that is no longer supported. For example, the class `CNNNetReader` does not exist in the latest OpenVINO. Does anyone know how to achieve this in new releases? (2020+)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this? First you need to read-in a model, the iterate over the nodes in the graph and filter the Constants (I'm making a copy here because the nodes are held as shared pointers). Then each Constant node can be transformed into a vector of values if you're looking for that. To do that you can use the templated method `cast_vector<T>` and you can figure out which type to use by checking what the Constant holds (using `get_element_type`).

```
const auto model = core.read_model("path");

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ov::op::v0::Constant>> weights;
const auto ops = model->get_ops();
std::copy_if(std::begin(ops), std::end(ops), std::back_inserter(weights), [](const std::shared_ptr<ov::Node>& op) {
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<ov::op::v0::Constant>(op) != nullptr;
});

for (const auto& w : weights) {
    if (w->get_element_type() == ov::element::Type_t::f32) {
        const std::vector<float> floats = w->cast_vector<float>();
    } else if (w->get_element_type() == ov::element::Type_t::i32) {
        const std::vector<int32_t> ints = w->cast_vector<int32_t>();
    } else if (...) { 
        ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone who want to do this in Python, you can pass the Node object to Numpy array constructor like `np.array(node)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the class [`Core`](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/api/ie_python_api/_autosummary/openvino.runtime.Core.html) and the method [`read_model`](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/api/ie_python_api/_autosummary/openvino.runtime.Core.html#openvino.runtime.Core.read_model) to read the model. Next, use the methods in the class [`Model`](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/api/ie_python_api/_autosummary/openvino.runtime.Model.html) to get the detail for each layer.

```
import openvino.runtime as ov

ie = ov.Core()

network = ie.read_model('face-detection-adas-0001.xml')

# print(network.get_ops())

# print(network.get_ordered_ops())

# print(network.get_output_op(0))

# print(network.get_result())
```

Refer to [OpenVINO Python API](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/api/ie_python_api/api.html) and [OpenVINO Runtime C++ API](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/groupov_cpp_api.html) for more information.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).